# Can we use SQL Server 2016 for SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, content-database, database-attach

I have a SharePoint 2013 Foundation single server farm. My current SQL version is "SQL Server 2008 R2".

I have another server with SQL Server 2016 version and I want to move all content databases to my SQL Server 2016 (using content database detach and attach method).

1. Is it possible to use SQL Server 2016 for SharePoint 2013?
2. Can we use SQL Server 2016 by changing the compatibility level of database from database properties?
3. Any other way to be able to SQL Server 2016 instance for SharePoint 2013?

or do I need to strictly use one of the supported SQL servers by SharePoint 2013 as per Microsoft documentation (SQL Server 2014/2012/2008 R2)?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

No, SQL Server 2016 is not supported with SharePoint 2013. As noted, maximum is SQL 2014  although that requires a baseline patch level (which you should have well exceeded by now given you're current on SharePoint patches).